# How to calculate the correlation between two categorical variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, correlation, categorical-data, cross-correlation

I have a dataset containing two columns:

```
| Food.    | Gender   |
| -------- | -------- |
| Soup.    | Female   |
| Chicken  | Male     |
| Beef     | Male     |
| Chicken  | Female   |
```

(it goes on)
I would like to calculate the correlation between these two variables. I have seen some methods but they mostly consider the two variables being binary, however, it is not the case for my Food variable (there is 4 types of food they can eat).

Thank you very much :)

```
CrosstabResult = pd.crosstab(index=df['FOOD'], columns=df['GENDER'])
print(CrosstabResult)

# importing the required function
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

# Performing Chi-sq test
ChiSqResult = chi2_contingency(CrosstabResult)

# P-Value is the Probability of H0 being True
# If P-Value&gt;0.05 then only we Accept the assumption(H0)

print('The P-Value of the ChiSq Test is:', ChiSqResult[1])
```

Comment: The code works and the results seem consistency? What's the problem / question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [Cramer V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)'s coefficient as a measurement of multilabel categorical variables association. This can be implemented with [scipy.stats.contingency.association](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.contingency.association.html) via the following code example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FOOD':['Soup']*16 + ['Chicken']*4 + ['Beef'] *10,
                   'GENDER':['Male','Male','Male','Female','Male'] * 6})
CrosstabResult = pd.crosstab(index=df['FOOD'], columns=df['GENDER'])
```

With a resulting table:

```
GENDER   Female  Male
FOOD                 
Beef          2     8
Chicken       1     3
Soup          3    13
```

Allows us to implement the *scipy's association* function which by default uses Cramer method (although this can be changed for tschuprow or pearson):

```
association_metric = association(CrosstabResult)
```

And then printing the output:

```
print("The association variable between",CrosstabResult.index.name,"and",CrosstabResult.columns.name,"is:",association_metric)
```

Returning:

```
The association variable between FOOD and GENDER is: 0.05103103630798288
```

Do keep in mind however, that this is not exactly a correlation coefficient as described in the documentation:

> Cramer’s V, Tschuprow’s T and Pearson’s Contingency Coefficient, all measure the degree to which two nominal or ordinal variables are related, or the level of their association. This differs from correlation, although many often mistakenly consider them equivalent. Correlation measures in what way two variables are related, whereas, association measures how related the variables are.

**Consistency Test**

If I slightly tweak the data so that `Soup` and `Chicken` seem to be only consumed by `Male`, whereas `Beef` by `Female`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FOOD':['Soup']*16 + ['Chicken']*4 + ['Beef'] *10,
                   'GENDER':['Male'] * 20 + ['Female'] * 10})
```

Which after crosstabbing looks like this:

```
GENDER   Female  Male
FOOD                 
Beef         10     0
Chicken       0     4
Soup          0    16
```

Then logically the association should be very strong (since there is a perfect relationship). Proving the implementation is correct, printing the previous lines of codes:

```
association_metric = association(CrosstabResult)
print("The association variable between",CrosstabResult.index.name,"and",CrosstabResult.columns.name,"is:",association_metric)
```

Correctly returns:

```
The association variable between FOOD and GENDER is: 0.9999999999999999
```